# How effective was Civil War-era artillery in the rain?

Tags: military, 19th-century, american-civil-war, artillery

How did rain effect cannon of the mid-19th century? Specifically the commonly fielded types like the 12-pounder Napoleon. Could they operate effectively and reliably in heavy rainfall?

I’ve been able to [find information](https://civilwartalk.com/threads/rain-impact-on-civil-war-weapons.161207/) on the effectiveness of various small arms in inclement weather, but not anything useful on the big guns.

Comment: Decent question. However, providing links to your prior research on small arms might entice more up-votes.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Question updated with link to prior research.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The book [The Artillerist's Manual](https://books.google.com/books?id=8FEkwTZd9FMC&printsec=frontcover&dq=civil%20war%20era%20cannon%2012%20pounder%20napoleon%20touch%20hole%20rain&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjh44bitcPoAhWGv54KHabzDBAQ6AEwAXoECAYQAg#v=onepage&q=friction&f=false) By John Gibbon, from 1860 gives us some insight into what was in use at the time. A clip from the appendix page 13 shows the components of an ammo box distributed with 12-pound guns and Howitzers.

[image]

The last three items on the list are included to provide various means of firing the weapon; the friction primer, the slow match, and the portfire.

**The [friction primer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction_primer)** was probably the primary item used by this time to detonate the cannon charge.  Note the packs of 48 and 60 included in these packages. These were self-contained and packed in their own container to keep dry and ready. They operated by friction, so a pull on a lanyard would set off the priming powder. No external spark necessary. From a [NPS website](https://www.nps.gov/parkhistory/online_books/source/is3/is3b1.htm):

> The device was a copper tube (fig. 19) filled with powder. The tube
>   went into the vent of the cannon and buried its tip in the powder
>   charge. Near the top of this tube was soldered a "spur"—a short tube
>   containing a friction composition (antimony sulphide and potassium
>   chlorate). Lying in the composition was the roughened end of a wire
>   "slider." The other end of the slider was twisted into a loop for
>   hooking to the gunner's lanyard. It was like striking a match: a smart
>   pull on the lanyard, and the rough slider ignited the composition.
>   Then the powder in the long tube began to burn and fired the charge in
>   the cannon. Needless to say, it happened faster than we can tell it!

[image: friction primer]

---

The next two items would have served as backup in case of problems with the friction primers or they ran out.

---

**The [slow match](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow_match)**  was an older technology, and might have been more susceptible to moisture issues, as it required direct contact to some form of cartridge [fuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuse_(explosives)) or priming powder. From the same [NPS website](https://www.nps.gov/parkhistory/online_books/source/is3/is3b1.htm):

> Before 1800, the slow match was in universal use for setting off the
>   charge. The match was usually a 3-strand cotton rope, soaked in a
>   solution of saltpeter and otherwise chemically treated with lead
>   acetate and lye to burn very slowly—about 4 or 5 inches an hour. It
>   was attached to a linstock (fig. 18), a forked stick long enough to
>   keep the cannoneer out of the way of the recoil.

---

**The portfire**, the final entry,  would have been a failsafe for all-weather use, as it was used in naval artillery where constant water exposure would have been an issue.

An glossary entry from the website [civilwarartillery](http://www.civilwarartillery.com/glossary/glossarygz.htm)

> PORTFIRE: A composition of nitre, sulphur, and mealed powder driven
>   into a case of strong paper. Portfire was used to fire guns previous
>   to the introduction of the friction primer. It was also used in
>   emergency situations and to fire rockets. A full length portfire would
>   burn for about ten minutes and **could not be extinguished by water**.

So of the several options discussed in the 1860 book linked above, most had some degree of functionality in adverse weather conditions.

Comment: A lede would improve this answer.